# 6-day curie to grams?

Tags: radiation, units, radioactivity, medical-physics

I am a pre-med interested in nuclear medicine. I recently came upon this wonderous radioisotope called Mo-99 (which decays into Technetium-99m), but in their industry, they measure the quantity of this radioisotope using a convoluted measurement system called a "6-day curie."

If there is anybody in nuclear medicine, can you assist me in converting a "6-day curie" to grams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [6-day curie is an outdated unit](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10967-015-4050-4) that originated when the average time between isotope production and clinical use was about 6 days.  It is nominally defined as the amount of Mo-99 that 6 days later will have an activity of 1 [curie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_(unit)). The half-life of [Mo-99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_molybdenum) is
$$t_{1/2}=2.748\,\mathrm{days} = 2.374\times10^5\,\mathrm{seconds}$$
so after 6 days the activity will be 22.01% of the initial activity, i.e. one 6-day curie corresponds to an initial activity of
$$\frac{dN_0}{dt} = \frac{1}{0.2201}=4.54\,\mathrm{curies} = 1.68\times 10^{11}\,\mathrm{becquerels}$$
The mean-life of Mo-99 is
$$\tau = \ln{2}\times t_{1/2}=3.425\times10^5\,\mathrm{seconds}$$
Since a [becquerel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Becquerel) is one decay per second, the initial number of Mo-99 atoms in a 6-day Curie is
$$N_0 = \frac{dN_0}{dt} \times \tau=3.99\times{10^{16}}\,\textrm{Mo-99 atoms}$$
The atomic mass of Mo-99 is
$$A({^{99}\mathrm{Mo}})=98.9077\,\mathrm{daltons}$$
and 1 [dalton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalton_(unit)) $=1.660538921\times 10^{-24}\,\mathrm{grams}$, so a 6-day Curie of Mo-99 has a mass of
$$m = A({^{99}\mathrm{Mo}})\times \mathrm{1\,dalton}\times N_0=6.55\,\mathrm{µg}$$

Comment: Thank you so much!